# Как лучше записывать в MySql из txt в 52к записей используя JS и PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

Задача дать пользователю записать в базу рассылки из текстового файла ID с количеством в 50к записей.

пример файла:

```
121747610
133653942
140871606
142220810
143501526
```

Сам файл я прочитываю JS и формирую массив ID.Варианта записи есть у меня два

HTML

```
<input type="file" id="file">
<button onclick="read()">
Read!
</button>
<div id="out">undefined</div>
```

JS

```
function readFile(object, callback) {
      var file = object.files[0]
      console.log(file)
      var reader = new FileReader()
      reader.onload = function() {
      callback(reader.result)
        console.log(reader)
      }
      reader.readAsText(file)
    }
    function saveFile(data, name){
      var a=document.createElement("a")
      a.setAttribute("download", name||"file.txt")
      a.setAttribute("href", "data:application/octet-stream;base64,"+btoa(data||"undefined"))
      a.click()
    }
    function read(){
      var file = document.getElementById("file").files[0]
      console.log("Loading \""+file.name+"\"... ("+Math.round(file.size/1024)+"kB)")
      if(file.size>=256*1024){
        if(!confirm("File size is "+Math.round(file.size/1024)+"kBytes! Really want to read it?")){
          console.log("Aborting loading file...")
          return
        }
      }
      var reader = new FileReader()
      reader.onload = function() {
        console.log("File readed!")
        var groupList = reader.result;
        var arrGroupList = groupList.split('\r\n');
        document.getElementById("out").innerHTML=JSON.stringify(arrGroupList)

        console.log(arrGroupList.length);

        /* groupList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arrGroupList));
        groupList.forEach(function(groupLine) {
            groupLine;
        }); */
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();         
        xhr.open('POST', '/php/inmport.php');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');          
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(arrGroupList));
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
          if (this.readyState == 4) 
          {
            if (this.status == 200)
            {
              console.log(xhr.responseText);
            }
            else
            {
              console.log('ajax error');
            }
          }
        };

      }
      console.log("Starting reading file...")
      reader.readAsText(file)
    }
```

1) Тупо отправить в PHP массив и заставить ждать записи всех данных.

2) Поочередно записывать ID можно сказать партиями с промежутком времени.

**Как вообще это лучше делается?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю, подойдет ли Вам, но я бы сделал примерно так:

```
//Получаем содержимое файла в виде массива
$content = file('file.txt');

//Перебираем все элементы массива в цикле
foreach ($content as $string) {
    //Записываем в MySQL
}
```